# Online File Management(Django)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-design, file-management

I am creating a django based website in which user can create folders and store some text (specifically urls and their 1 line description) in a hierarchical folder way .The site will contain a login option after that user can create folders and inside them subfolders and inside the sub folders, the user can store url and their description.

I need help in set up of database so that whenever a user logins and click on a particular folder he/she can view his/her folders and their content and create new sub folders and delete them. I am trying to use postgresql, i am all okay with the front end but the main thing in which i need help is how to create database for each folders and how to load them in my website.

PS: I am trying to keep a constraint that if a user has created folder 'A' he/she can store text but if a sub folder 'B' is created the user cannot store links in 'A'(parent folder) the links needs to be stored in the sub folders and notify to move the previously stored links to a sub folder. Same goes for the sub folders. Example now 'B' can have sub folders 'C' and 'D'.

I have tried my best to be explicit about my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try these django packages listed here: (https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/file-managers/)

Comment: @SammyJ Thanks for the help but these packages didn't help me. If you have some other alternative solution please suggest me.

Comment: During a recent search, I also did not find many options for user-facing file management from the packages listed on Djangopackages.org. @aashu, did you end up solving the problem?